# How many different versions of 'x' are accessible in (*)?

Tags: java, inner-classes

This is a training exercise for understanding the workings of inner classes in Java. As the question states, how many different versions of `x` are accessible in `(*)`?

```
class Outer {
    int x;

    class Inner extends Outer {
        int x;

        void f(int x) {
            (*)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm inclined to think that there are 3, namely: `this.x`, `super.x` and `x` but some of my peers seem to think that there are 4.

Which of us is confused? And can you explain?

Comment: Bleaaah, what a mess of code.  But I'm leaning towards 4, distinguishing `Outer.this.x` from `super.x`, because you have `Outer` as both a supertype and an enclosing type, and those are distinct.

Comment: Correct. With  `Outer a = new Outer(); Inner b = a.new Inner();` there's 4 of them.

Comment: some more syntactic forms - `Inner.super.x` , `((Outer)this).x`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are 4, namely: `x`, `this.x`, `super.x` and `Outer.this.x`.

Consider the following:

```
public class Outer {

    int x;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        Outer.Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
        outer.x = 3;
        inner.x = 2;
        inner.f(1);
    }

    class Inner extends Outer {
        int x;

        void f(int x) {
            System.out.println(super.x);
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(this.x);
            System.out.println(Outer.this.x);
        }
    }

}
```

This code will print

```
0
1
2
3
```

showing 4 different values.

What's happening is the following:

1. The parent of the `inner` instance has an unitialized `x` variable. For an `int`, the default value is 0: this is `super.x`.
2. The method `f` is called with the argument `1`: this is `x`.
3. The instance `inner` was set its `x` to 2 with `inner.x = 2`: this is `this.x`.
4. The `outer` instance, which is `Outer.this` was set its `x` value to 3: this is `Outer.this.x`.

---

The trick here is that `Inner` is both an [inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) (so it has an enclosing `Outer` instance) and a [subclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4) (so it has a parent `Outer` instance), and those two `Outer` instances are not the same.

Comment: Re: "a [subclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4) (so it has a parent `Outer` instance)": This should be "a [subclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4) (so it is itself an `Outer` instance)". (Or rather: "a [subclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4) (so its instances are themselves `Outer` instances)".)

Answer (score 11):

There are four of them:

- `Outer.this.x` for the `Outer` class property
- `this.x` for the `Inner` class property
- `super.x` for the super type `Outer` class property
- `x` for the method argument